# Java networking, error checking and database

Tags: java, javascript, database, network-programming

Java networking

you are given a simple
Java GUI and asked to modify it by adding error-checking and
establishing database connectivity.

Does anyone know any code for error-checking and database connectivity?

Comment: What have you tired? What sort of data connectivity? Checking what for errors?

Comment: no is just a question i got for 2morrow...i just need different codes..

Comment: Junior these open-ended broad questions tend to Dv's quickl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean exception handling which can be easily done in java like this:

```
try {
   //the code
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); //print exception
}
```

As for database connecting, it often happens in steps:

**JDBC (For example)**

- Loading Driver
- Establishing Connection
- Executing Statements
- Getting Results
- Closing Database Connection

Because I am quite unsure as to what you have done so far I will give a link to an example that handles this quite well (Do note this is just JDBC and there are others out there)

[JDBC example](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-steps.shtml)